# Check if array of integers increments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to check if an arrays values once sorted are incrementing by 1

For example

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = TRUE
[1, 2, 8, 9, 10] = FALSE
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: I'd hope not considering I don't go to school.

Comment: IIRC, there's another question that asks how to extract lists of consecutive elements from an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def array_increments_by?(step, array)
  sorted = array.sort
  lastNum = sorted[0]
  sorted[1, sorted.count].each do |n|
    if lastNum + step != n
      return false
    end
    lastNum = n
  end
  true
end
```

Usage:

```
array_increments?(1, [0,1,2,3]) #=> true
array_increments?(2, [0,2,4,6]) #=> true
array_increments?(2, [0,2,4,8]) #=> false
```

Comment: I think you need 'lastNum = sorted[0]' otherwise 'array_increments_by?(1, [3,2,1,0])' fails.

Comment: Spot on, i was close to this the bit i was doing exactly the same as your old version was setting my base number(i.e your lastNum) to array[0] rather than the pre sorted array. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

```
array = [1,2,4,3]
array.sort.each_cons(2).all? { |x,y| y == x + 1 }
```

Comment: Thank you for using `each_cons` in this example.  That makes it beautiful.

Comment: Awesome; my first encounter with each_cons and it makes this and other situations so easy... thanks!

Comment: This is incorrect. Remove the `sort` else it'll always return true.

Answer (score 5):

```
def continguous?(arr)
  a = arr.sort
  (a.first..a.last).to_a == a
end

a = [2,1,3,4,5]
p continguous?(a)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

I go with this:

```
def is_consecutive_array?(ary)
  sorted_array  = ary.sort
  first_element = sorted_array.first
  last_element  = sorted_array.last
  ((last_element - first_element) == ary.size - 1) && (sorted_array[0].upto(sorted_array[-1]).to_a == sorted_array)
end

is_consecutive_array?([1,2])           # => true
is_consecutive_array?([1,2,3])         # => true
is_consecutive_array?([3,2,1])         # => true
is_consecutive_array?([-1,0,1])        # => true
is_consecutive_array?([1,3])           # => false
is_consecutive_array?([1, 2, 2, 2, 5]) # => false
```

This is a change from the previous version. I wasn't happy with it but couldn't put my finger on why. @sawa pointed out the flaw which is in the last test above. I added the `&&` section to do an exhaustive check if the first test returns true. The overall effect shows up in this benchmark:

```
Benchmark.bm do |_bench|

  ary2 = ary[0 .. -3] + ary[-1,1]
  _bench.report { loops.times {
    is_consecutive_array?(ary2)
  }}

  _bench.report { loops.times {
    is_consecutive_array?(ary)
  }}

end
# >>       user     system      total        real
# >>   2.140000   0.200000   2.340000 (  2.328039)
# >>  18.430000   0.020000  18.450000 ( 18.442234)
```

Most arrays will not be consecutive, and will not have the right combination to fool the first test. For those that do, the second test should catch it.

---

EDIT: Here are some benchmarks to compare the various suggested methods. The answers up to this point in time have been preserved as closely as possible. I had to change the `increase_by?` answer because it was patching Array and wasn't sorting. I didn't want it to accidentally have a detrimental effect on the other tests or an unfair advantage.

NOTE: I raised the TIMEOUT_LIMIT because I also made the test array bigger.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'timeout'

TIMEOUT_LIMIT = 60 # in seconds

ary = [*(1..10_000)]
loops = 10_000

def is_consecutive_array?(ary)
  sorted_array  = ary.sort
  first_element = sorted_array.first
  last_element  = sorted_array.last
  ((last_element - first_element) == ary.size - 1) && (sorted_array[0].upto(sorted_array[-1]).to_a == sorted_array)
end
is_consecutive_array?([1,2])           # => true
is_consecutive_array?([1,2,3])         # => true
is_consecutive_array?([3,2,1])         # => true
is_consecutive_array?([-1,0,1])        # => true
is_consecutive_array?([1,3])           # => false
is_consecutive_array?([1, 2, 2, 2, 5]) # => false

def sawa(a)
  b = a.dup
  x = b.delete(b.min)
  nil while b.delete(x+=1)
  b.empty?
end
sawa([1,2])   # => true
sawa([1,3])   # => false
sawa([1,3,3]) # => false

def array_increments_by?(step, array)
  sorted = array.sort
  lastNum = sorted[0]
  sorted[1, sorted.count].each do |n|
    if lastNum + step != n
      return false
    end
    lastNum = n
  end
  true
end
array_increments_by?(1,[1,2])   # => true
array_increments_by?(1,[1,3])   # => false
array_increments_by?(1,[1,3,3]) # => false

def continguous?(arr)
  a = arr.sort
  (a.first..a.last).to_a == a
end
continguous?([1,2])   # => true
continguous?([1,3])   # => false
continguous?([1,3,3]) # => false

def fgb(array)
  array.sort.each_cons(2).all? { |x,y| y == x + 1 }
end
fgb([1,2])   # => true
fgb([1,3])   # => false
fgb([1,3,3]) # => false

# changed from a monkey-patch on Array to avoid any unintended side-effects.
def increase_by?(ary, n)
  ary.sort # added sort to put on same ground as all other tests
  y = nil
  ary.each {|x| return false if y && ((x-y) != n); y=x}
  true
end
increase_by?([1,2],1)   # => true
increase_by?([1,3],1)   # => false
increase_by?([1,3,3],1) # => false

Benchmark.bm(20) do |_bench|

  begin
    testname = 'is_consecutive_array?'
    status = Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT_LIMIT) { _bench.report(testname) { loops.times { is_consecutive_array?(ary) } } }
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "#{testname} timed out"
  end

  begin
    testname = 'sawa'
    status = Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT_LIMIT) { _bench.report(testname) { loops.times { sawa(ary) } } }
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "#{testname} timed out"
  end

  begin
    testname = 'array_increments_by?'
    status = Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT_LIMIT) { _bench.report(testname) { loops.times { array_increments_by?(1, ary) } } }
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "#{testname} timed out"
  end

  begin
    testname = 'continguous?'
    status = Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT_LIMIT) { _bench.report(testname) { loops.times { continguous?(ary) } } }
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "#{testname} timed out"
  end

  begin
    testname = 'fgb'
    status = Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT_LIMIT) { _bench.report(testname) { loops.times { fgb(ary) } } }
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "#{testname} timed out"
  end

  begin
    testname = 'increase_by?'
    status = Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT_LIMIT) { _bench.report(testname) { loops.times { increase_by?(ary, 1) } } }
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "#{testname} timed out"
  end
end
```

And the results against a consecutive array:

```
# >>                           user     system      total        real
# >> is_consecutive_array? 18.470000   0.020000  18.490000 ( 18.476536)
# >> sawa                sawa timed out
# >> array_increments_by? 37.070000   0.670000  37.740000 ( 37.734562)
# >> continguous?         18.720000   0.890000  19.610000 ( 19.590057)
# >> fgb                 fgb timed out
# >> increase_by?         41.510000   0.610000  42.120000 ( 42.090960)
```

Comment: @the Tin Man, That's sad for me. I will take off from my answer the part mentioning the speed.

Comment: @the Tin Man Obviously, your answer is the best.

Comment: @the Tin Man I just realized that your answer will incorrectly judge that an array like `[1, 2, 2, 2, 5]` is consecutive.

Comment: @the Tin Man Yours is still the fastest. Good.

Comment: It will drop to 2 seconds on non-continuous arrays because of the trapdoor. The final benchmark doesn't reflect that. Maybe tomorrow I'll update it with a more comprehensive test.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Thanks for this, i was quick to jump the gun. But considering the nature of the task, reducing the time by half is a big thing for me. This is awesome. Could you explain why your method is faster? Thanks again.

Comment: It does a quick test knowing that `last element - first element` should be the length of the `array - 1`. If it isn't it's not a consecutive array. Most of the time that should weed out arrays. If that returns true then it'll test again more exhaustively. For most arrays that short test is sufficient so its very fast. If a lot of huge consecutive arrays are tested it will slow down but will still be efficient. The initial test will slow it down a tiny bit at that point. Overall it's very fast. Timing varies a little so the two fastest could periodically switch unless my test hits.

Comment: The big lesson is to use benchmarks to develop an algorithm, and don't assume that the first attempt is fast enough. By trying different things you can incrementally speed it up. The other lesson is that some algorithms are fast for short arrays but slow down as the array size increases so you have to balance what you want based on what you'll be doing.

Answer (score 1):

This one doesn't require `sort`.

```
a = [2, 8, 1, 9, 10]
b = a.dup
x = b.delete(b.min)
nil while b.delete(x+=1)
b.empty?
```

Answer (score 0):

If the difference between `a[i+1]` and `a[i]` is not equal to 1, then it is obvious that they are not either in increasing order incremented by 1 or not at all in increasing order ( considering no two elements in the array are equal). Run the loop from zero to length of array minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def increase_by?(n)
    y = nil
    self.each {|x| return false if y && ((x-y) != n); y=x}
    true
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].increase_by?(1) # => true
[1, 2, 8, 9, 10].increase_by?(1) # => false
```

Comment: You should not monkey patch unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Jacob: yeah, I guess so, it's just so much fun =)

Comment: @Julio: modifying built-in classes.  Notice that I add this method to the Array class instead of my own class; the practice is comparable to adding functions to the prototype of JavaScript objects and is frowned upon for good reasons.  I just happen to like doing it for small examples.

Answer (score 0):

### A short and efficient method

`sort` not required and comparison breaks at first counter-example.

```rb
def increase_by? (array, step)
    yes = true
    array.reduce { |l, r| break unless yes &= ( l+step == r ); l }
    yes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[a.size-1] == a[0] + a.size-1
TRUE
```

Comment: This could use a little more explanation of what you are actually doing.

Comment: This assumes the array is sorted and has no duplicates. It wouldn't work for a = [1, 5, 5, 5, 5] for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def increase_by_one?(array)
  temp = array.first
  array.each_with_index do |val, index|
   return false unless temp == val-index
  end
  true 
end
```