# Rails, evaluate if numbers are in sequence

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to evaluate the order of an array?  I want to find an array of records ordered by created_at date and then see if the numbers in that array are in sequence?

For instance:

```
  Model.all.order(&:created_at).select("lesson_number)
  [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

should fail because the numbers are not in sequence

I could execute two finds.  One that is ordered by "lesson_number" and one that is ordered by created_at date.  Convert them both the a string then compare the two.  But, seems like a lot of work if a rails method exists to handle such a thing.

Comment: another resource for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682940/check-if-array-of-integers-increments-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a couple methods in Ruby to do this pretty efficiently.

```
input.each_cons(2).reduce(true) { |result, (a, b)| result && (a <=> b) < 0 }
```

`each_cons` will iterate through your array yielding, in this case, each 2 consecutive items. Because we don't pass it a block, it returns an enumerator that we can iterate through and get a single resulting value using `reduce` (a.k.a. `inject`).

Our block compares `a` and `b` using `<=>` which will return -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the first value is "less-than", equal, or "greater than". In this case, we want to make sure `a` is `-1`.

In case you're not familiar with it, the parenthesis in the block argument are Ruby 1.9+, and they allow the arguments to be splatted in (otherwise we would get a 2-item array in our block).